# External USB drive enclosures: Plastic or Metallic for better heat dissipation?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, cooling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is an external hard disk with a metallic chasing better for heat dissipation than a plastic one?](https://superuser.com/questions/317315/is-an-external-hard-disk-with-a-metallic-chasing-better-for-heat-dissipation-than)

I noticed a metallic casing is warmer for the same disk than a plastic one. Is it better for heat dissipation to use the metallic one? I suspect the plastic one traps it.